# gulp-babel with babel-preset-env ignores browserslist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, gulp-babel

I'm trying to transpile some ES2015 code with Babel using gulp-babel but Babel seems to ignore my browserslist. Babel transpiles some modern features, but not all that would be needed to target the specified browser.

In my minimal example I use `Element.remove()` and target IE 9. Then, as [IE 9 doesn't support that feature](https://caniuse.com/#feat=childnode-remove), I would expect Babel to transpile that line to something like `Element.parentNode.removeChild(Element)`. But that doesn't happen and instead my `Element.remove()` line is unchanged.

The results don't change if I enter my browserslist in a `.browserslistrc` file or just remove my browserslist completely.

As this is my first attempt at transpiling code, I guess that I could just be mistaken as to what Babel actually should do.

### Minimal example

In my test folder I have a **package.json**

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0-beta.2"
    },
    "browserslist": "IE 9"
}
```

and a **gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/script.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The ES6 file **script.js** in the "src" folder is

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const myId = 'test';
    const myDiv = document.getElementById(`${myId}`);
    myDiv.remove();
});
```

which Babel (through the Gulp task `js`) transpiles to another **script.js** (in the "dist" folder)

```
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var myId = 'test';
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("".concat(myId));
    myDiv.remove();
});
```

So, the arrow function is replaced by a normal function, `const` is changed to `var` and the template literal is changed to regular string concatenation, but the `remove()` is left as is.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is it simply that I expect too much of Babel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken as to what Babel actually does with code. [As per the Babel website](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html#polyfill) “Babel only transforms syntax” so the observed behavior is exactly what should be expected.

I guess there are more clever solutions out there (such as Polyfill.io), but right now I’m solving these things with regular expressions in my gulpfile.js through `gulp-replace` with

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/script.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }))
        .pipe(replace(/(\S*)\.remove\s*\(.*?\)\s*;/g, '$1.parentNode.removeChild($1);'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: That regex is terrifying. Why not rely on the work other devs have already done to determine browser compatibility using things like polyfill.io?

Comment: @JacobStamm :-D In this case it felt a bit over the top to load another library for what was such a simple thing. As I wrote in my answer, I realize that there ought to be better solutions.